# Prevent MenuItem from closing the Menu - Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, menu, menuitem

I'm having problems trying to achieve the following: I need that when I click on an Item (MenuItem) from the Blackberry Menu, the Menu remains open. I tried to create a Menu custom on my own and overwrite the close function, but it didn't worked. So if anybody has a better idea please post it.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit weird what you are trying to achieve, and I'd strongly advise against it. It is not intuitive, and you probably can do the same using other mechanism.

But anyway, you could try to programmatically open the menu again once the MenuItem has been selected.

Comment: Hi @MisterSmith, what I'm trying to achieve is to have a SubMenu once you click a MenuItem, is something like when you want to send/share any context, you open the native blackberry menu, then click on Send and it opens a submenu with the apps you are able to share with, like this: http://rimhelpblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/send-videos-4.jpg?w=480&h=360 . The thing is that in 5.0 OS this is apparently imposible, so I made a custom menu that will open once you click the Share MenuItem. Now, I already tryed what you suggest and the Menu blocks the entire app once is open.

Comment: The `SubMenu` class is only available since OS 6.0. If you want to support previous versions, you could build your own (A menu is just a popup screen with a listfield inside). This could be tricky to emulate, so I'd just resort to dialogs for OS < 6, and use submenus from 6 onwards. But if you want to create a trully consistent UI for every OS, then give up on submenus and use only dialogs. They have several advantages, like having more room for text, unlimited number of items, and they are always centered so they are independent of their deep in the options tree.